# Universal Image Loader only download to SD Card and don't display

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

Is there a way to just download images to SD card from urls and not display them or keep them in memory but still keep all the goodies that UIL provides such as file name generation so that when you go to display the image it is already on disc and just waiting to be displayed?

I also would like to keep other images in memoryCache while these download so they are prompt to display and turning off memoryCache itself is not an option for me.

I noticed there was a method `loadImage(String uri, ImageLoadingListener listener)` but it's method `onLoadingComplete` already caches the image in memory as well...

Would appreciate any information if available.

Comment: Is not working out of the box: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016619/how-can-i-just-download-image-with-universal-image-loader