# Get Bitmap from universal image loader

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to get a bitmap resource using the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) Library. I have overridden the onLoadComplete() method like this:

```
loader.displayImage(thumbnail.get(position), hold.ivThumbnailReflection, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1, FailReason arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String urlLink, View arg1, Bitmap loadedImage) {

            Log.i("loading complete","loading complete "+loadedImage);
            hold.ivThumbnail.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);


        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

The image is set in the `ivThumbnailReflection` view but there is no image on the `ivThumbnail` view. When I print the object for loadedImage I get a string in the form- android.graphics.Bitmap@4170f1d0.

What am I doing wrong? Pls help.

**Edit:** Initialize options for UIL:

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.cacheOnDisc(true)
.bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
.build();
```

Comment: here loadedImage is your bitmap that you required

Comment: Are you sure the `ivThumbnail` is assigned and not null?

Comment: @Antonio if **ivThumbnail** is null then there will be a null pointer exception at this line of code at run time

Comment: I've assigned ivThumbnail - holder.ivThumbnail=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCarousel); using a holder class

Comment: can you also provide how you initialize `options`.

Comment: @Antonio I've edited my question. Included the options there. Pls have a look.

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you use only this instead of using complete :

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Or use this

```
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) 
    {
         // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
    }
});
```

Comment: Ive got to set the image twice. displayImage() does indeed show me the image once. To show the second image I need a bitmap

Comment: In above second type you are getting **loadedImage** as bitmap, you can use thisone for second image

Comment: I've tried using **hold.ivThumbnail.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);**. But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Then you must check this link for your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016619/how-can-i-just-download-image-with-universal-image-loader

Comment: can I use Universal image loader, if I only have bitmap and an imageview, no url?

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra, you can use Android-Universal-Image-Loader and here are the image sources which it supports: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#acceptable-uris-examples

Answer (score 5):

Try using `loadImageSync(String uri)` . It gives you bitmap.

If you want drawable from bitmap

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),imageLoader.loadImageSync(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code must help you

```
public class CreateNotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NetworkImageView mNetworkImageView;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    Bitmap bit;

    String url = "http://www.whitegadget.com/attachments/pc-wallpapers/145032d1392006652-nature-wallpaper-nature-picture.jpg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_notification);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.networkImageView1);

        //bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bgd);

        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bgd);

        mImageLoader = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                .getImageLoader();

        Bitmap bitmap =mImageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(mNetworkImageView,
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.drawable.icon)).getBitmap();



        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createNotification();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mImageLoader = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                .getImageLoader();

        bit =mImageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(mNetworkImageView,
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.drawable.icon)).getBitmap();


    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public void createNotification()
    {



        bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bgd);

        mImageLoader.get(url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {
                bit =mImageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(mNetworkImageView,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable
                                .ic_dialog_alert)).getBitmap();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);


                Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setContentTitle("Mail Notification")
                        .setContentText("5 new unread messages")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bgd)
                        .setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bit))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();


                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                notificationManager.notify(0,noti);

                Log.i("LOG>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>","inside the on response");
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bgd);
                Log.i("LOG>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>","inside the errror response");


            }
        });

//        bit =mImageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(mNetworkImageView,
//                R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable
//                        .ic_dialog_alert)).getBitmap();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the bitmap in ui thread either by using a Handler or by using runOnUiThread(..) method as follows:

```
handler..post(new Runnable() { // handler must be initialized in UI thread

            @Override
            public void run() {
                hold.ivThumbnail.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);

            }
});
```

Or try using runOnUiThread() method as:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 hold.ivThumbnail.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Library should do it itself, if options handler assigned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create options in the main/UI thread.

Otherwise, extend the initialization of you `options` with handler assignment.

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
  .cacheOnDisc(true)
  .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
  .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
  .handler(yourHandler)
  .build();
```

where `yourHandler` should be created in the main/UI thread.