# Pre-downloading images with Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

How can I pre-download all images to disk-cache with Android-Universal-Image-Loader? I would like to allow user to download all images at once.

Comment: Is not working out of the box: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016619/how-can-i-just-download-image-with-universal-image-loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [v1.9.0](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v190-27112013) it is possible to download image synchronously:

```
ImageLoader.loadImageSync(...) : Bitmap
```

Now it's much more easier to download images in background (e.g. inside [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)).