# How do UIL(universal image loader) and Picasso organize download of images from different activities in background in queue?

Tags: android, android-service, universal-image-loader, picasso, android-service-binding

I need to download images from server  and store on my external storage.
Imagine we have different activities and when open the (A) activity I need to download "N" number images and  while the download of the "N" number of images is not complete I exit from activity,(it should continue downloading and storing images).I switch to another (B)activity where "M" number of images should be downloaded and stored .The download of "N" number of images is not complete ,while it should start download of "M " number of images ,(I mean the recently came images should download the first )and when  "M" number of images are downloaded it'll continue downloading the rest of "N" number of images.This process could continue for multiply activities.
I would like to know how I need to organize the queue of image downloading and is it possible to us UIL of Picasso ,which could solve my task easily.

Comment: Your question would be something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016619/how-can-i-just-download-image-with-universal-image-loader

Comment: Thanks ,only I would like to know how to organize thread execution  in LIFO order and only 1 thread should run others need to wait until the thread complete task?